# Garbage collector tuning in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I know about `GC.enable/disable`, but is there any way of controlling the Ruby **1.9** garbage collector in more detail?

When profiling my code (using perftools.rb) I notice that the GC stands for up to 30% of the total samples, and I'd like to see if it's possible to tune the GC to decrease this number. Are there any environment variables or other means by which you can set the number of heap slots, the malloc limit, etc. like you can with REE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There is no way to tune the 1.9.0–1.9.2 GC. However, you can compile a custom VM that exposes more or less the same tuning parameters as REE with [this patch](https://gist.github.com/856296).

Comment: The gist has a comment that GC configurability is being suggested in the issue tracker: http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/1047

Comment: 1.9.3 will have tuning parameters like REE has, but it's noisy. See the comments to this post: http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-3-preview-1-released-5229.html

Answer (score 11):

Yep, for short.

At first, basic constants, defining GC behavior (defaults value are shown) :

- RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT = 8000000 # - Initial size of a new memory slab, which is allocated after consuming all available memory
- RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS = 10000 #- Initial memory size, allocated at startup
- RUBY_HEAP_SLOTS_GROWTH_FACTOR = 1,8 #- New slab of memory is X times bigger than previous after each allocation.
- RUBY_HEAP_SLOTS_INCREMENT = 1 # Not sure, honestly :)

[More details about GC, may help](http://timetobleed.com/garbage-collection-slides-from-la-ruby-conference/)

[A story from](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2742-the-road-to-faster-tests) 37signals guys, which may definitively help you. They used manual GC calls (GC.start) on time, instead of memory size, and got huge boost.

Comment: Aman & Joe talk about these constants in their presentation, but from what I can tell they are actually the same REE settings I mentioned in my question. Am I wrong or can you give me an example of how to use them in a vanilla Ruby 1.9 VM?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is 1) only 1.8.7 and 2) even on 1.8.7 requires you to patch and compile a custom VM. There is a new patch for 1.9.2 that was released long after your answer, but it still requires you to compile a custom VM.