# Ruby Malloc Limit: How to raise it higher

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, garbage-collection, malloc, ruby-1.9

I am using ruby 1.9.3 with rails 3.1 and the memory usage for these things can get pretty large pretty fast. I have read around and it appears that the default ruby malloc limit is 8MB. This is pretty low and I have a lot of server to play around with. How can I raise the malloc limit to something like 1024 MB or so? I know the variable is RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT. I don't really want to have to custom compile the VM.

Comment: See this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985310/garbage-collector-tuning-in-ruby-1-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for this you could try the [malloc gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/malloc). You can custom set malloc items:

```
m = Malloc.new(1048576) #Number of bytes to allocate
```